# scala distinct() vs. spark distinct(), which is more efficient?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When processing large amount of data (around 10,000 rows of data), I want to make sure that there's **no duplicates** in the data.

Our work flow is to first read parquet files to spark `dataframes`, then convert `dataframes` into `scala case classes`.

There are two options to eliminate duplicates:

1. call scala `distinct()` on `Seq[caseClasses]`
2. call spark `distinct()` on `dataframes`

Digging into scala source code, I found that it goes through every record and put them in a `set`. Compared with spark, which way is more efficient?

Thanks!

Edits:
Original post said that the data size is 10,000, which is the size for our test data. Later the data size can go up to 5 million.

Comment: What hinders you taking own measurements?

Comment: I would say for 10'000 rows, do it in scala

Comment: 10000 is a very small amount of data unless the rows are themselves huge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: it depends...

The rule of thumb here is: the smaller the data, the more Spark's overhead gets in the way, and using plain Scala would be faster; The larger the data, the more likely it is for the Scala operation to simply run our of memory or choke the driver machine's CPU, and therefore using Spark would be a must. 10,000 records is usually small enough to fit on one machine (depending on the nature - size - of these records, of course) so plain Scala might be faster.

**Spark** will execute this using more than one machine, so given a large enough cluster it would be potentially faster. However, `distinct` requires shuffling the data between nodes (to eliminate duplicates on different nodes), which is slower (serialization, IO, network...).

**Scala** would only use the "driver" machine's CPU and memory for this - so potentially slower if it has little resources, but otherwise faster because no shuffling (network, serialization...) will be needed.

Another point to consider is: if you plan to eventually call `collect` anyway (collecting all data into Driver memory), and if `distinct` drastically shrinks your dataset, you'd gain something by executing `distinct` on the cluster (i.e. using Spark) because then you'll be able to `collect` less data (which means using less network resources, less serialization etc.).

Comment: Thanks! The data is not supposed to have duplicates, the `distinct` is to make sure that the inputs are valid. So `distinct` will not shrink the dataset in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the answer is Spark since the computation occurs on a distributed environment.